Session cookie is not stored in the browser - Spring Boot
I am creating a login with Spring Boot but apparently my session management is not working properly since the session is not stored in the browser even though it's send in the response.
important dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

config file:
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter){
        this.customAuthenticationFilter = customAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        RequestCache nullRequestCache = new NullRequestCache();
        return http
        .addFilterAt(customAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .disable()
        )
        .cors(cors -> cors
            .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers(PermittedEndpoints.list).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .requestCache(cache -> cache
            .requestCache(nullRequestCache)
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
        )
        .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository()))
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5173")); 
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
            new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
            new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
        serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID"); 
        serializer.setCookiePath("/"); 
        serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"); 
        serializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(true);
        serializer.setSameSite("Lax");
        serializer.setUseSecureCookie(true);
        return serializer;
    }
    
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
}

The idea is that an unauthenticated user is redirected to the login page when accessing a page that requires authentication. This works fine but when I try to register (saves the context to the SecurityContextRepository) and access an authenticated endpoint I still get redirected to the login page because the session is not returned and Spring creates a null authentication. I also tried it with postman and it works as expected there.
UPDATE
I didn't provide my Frontend code but the error was there. For my requests I'am using the Javascript Fetch API in React which looks like this:
useEffect(() => {
        async function authenticate(){
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/authenticate?${"u"}=${location}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers:{
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "credentials": "include"
                }
            })
            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error("Request failed");
            }
            const json = await response.json()
            setIsAuthenticated(json.value)
            if(json.value == "false"){
                navigate("/login")
            }
        }
        authenticate()
    }, [location, navigate])

I thought that "credentials": "include" is a header but it's part of the Fetch API so I just had to move this line out of the header to fix everything:
useEffect(() => {
        async function authenticate(){
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/authenticate?${"u"}=${location}`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers:{
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
                credentials: "include"
            })
            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error("Request failed");
            }
            const json = await response.json()
            setIsAuthenticated(json.value)
            if(json.value == "false"){
                navigate("/login")
            }
        }
        authenticate()
    }, [location, navigate])


Please try setting SameSite to None and setUseSecureCookie to false specifically for localhost.

your domainNamePattern expects a dot in the domain name (\.) - localhost wont have a dot

If you are testing over an HTTP connection then cookies will not be set as setUseSecureCookie is true. Either setUseSecureCookie to false or use HTTPs connection. Secure cookies are only sent over HTTPs. Secondly if your frontend is running on a different server and backend on different server then serializer.setSameSite("Lax") will not work, it should be serializer.setSameSite("None") instead.
In my project I was able to set cookies for JWT using following method:

Add HttpServletResponse in controller method as parameter
Set cookie manually

Example:
    public AuthResponse logonUser(HttpServletResponse response, LoginDTO requestBean){
                    String token = generateToken(requestBean);
                    ResponseCookie resCookie = ResponseCookie.from("your-cookie-name", token)
                            .httpOnly(true)
                            .sameSite("None")
                            .secure(true)
                            .path("/")
                            .maxAge(3600) //validity time in seconds
                            .build();
    
                    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, resCookie.toString());
    }


I tried using setUseSecureCookie(false) and setSameSite(“None”) but I still have the same problem and when I set the cookie manually, it is sent but not stored in the browser, just like the session cookie sent by Spring.

Have you tried setting response header? Also try removing setDomainNamePattern()

Yes I have. I copied your code for the test cookie and now both the session and test cookie are sent but still not saved or used for requests to the backend.

The error was in the Frontend I updated my question with the solution.
